# R Bookdown: Append chapter without re-rending whole book

Tags: r, markdown, bookdown

I am rather experienced with R but new to markdown and especially bookdown. I wonder how to render a single chapter and merge it with the existing book without re-building the whole book. The reason why I am asking is that I am creating a book that contains parameterised chapters and each chapter runs very long (1-2 hours). All in all, it will be hundreds of chapters with the same analysis, but different input data and would time-wise add up. I am aware of the [knit-and-merge](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html) approach, in fact, that's the reason why I chose bookdown, but somehow it is not working as expected.
I am honestly also a little bit confused by the different rendering possibilities. There is the built-book button, the knit button, serve_book(), render_book(), preview_chapter(), ... I figured that one should avoid using the knit button in bookdown and that serve_book() will automatically compile changes. My approach so far is entering serve_book() into console, where it renders the whole book, then I create a new chapter, hit save and it runs the chunks of only that chapter (exactly what I want!) and the single HTML file of the new chapter appears. However, it doesn't show them when I look at the book via the index.html file.
I am only interested in an HTML book and do not need any other output formats.
In order to recreate the problem, I am just using the bookdown example and adding chapters to it.

_bookdown.yaml

```
book_filename: "book_name"
new_session: yes #true
before_chapter_script: _common.R
delete_merged_file: true
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chapter "
```

_output.html

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  css: style.css
  theme:
    primary: "#10395B"
  #repo: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

_index.yaml

```
--- 
title: |
  ![](./Logo_PureGene.png){width=200px}|  
  |-|  
  ||

author: "Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
#output: bookdown::bs4_book
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
# url: your book url like https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown
# cover-image: path to the social sharing image like images/cover.jpg
description: |
  This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book.
  The HTML output format for this example is bookdown::bs4_book,
  set in the _output.yml file.
biblio-style: apalike
csl: chicago-fullnote-bibliography.csl
---



# About {-}
```

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you aware of the `cache` option ? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this option! But it seems like it could easily mess up the whole document. I will see if another solution comes up and give it a try after. Thanks!

Comment: This might be another option, knit separately and insert html : https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-html.html